# Dual display settings problem

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, games

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with dual displays in an extended display configuration. When I play any of several games both displays go to clone configuration and must be manually reset after the program is exited. What do I need to do to play on one monitor, or at least make the displays go back to original settings when done with game? Here is my info:

```
lee@lee-DX4860:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for lee: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff iopor
```